# Angular2 - how do i loop through child controls on a form

Tags: angular

I have a form set up and a loop to create a table of child components called "rating"

```
<form [formGroup]="ratingGroup">
.
.
.
        <ng-container *ngIf="ratings.length>0">
        <tr *ngFor="let name of measureNames">
            <td class="col-sm-1">{{name}}</td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let rating of ratings | groupFilter: name ">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let key of rating | keys">
                    <td class="col-sm-1" *ngIf="key=='measureRating'"><rating formControlName="singleRating" [selectedRating]="rating[key]"></rating></td>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

When i press an update button i want to loop through all the "rating" controls looking at their values.  I'm guessing the way is through a formgroup and formarray / formcontrol mix but i dont know how to set it up.